# How can I merge multiple lists of files together with CMake?

Tags: file, list, cmake, concatenation, glob

I have a project built with CMake that needs to copy some resources to the destination folder. Currently I use this code:

```
file(GLOB files "path/to/files/*")
foreach(file ${files})
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        TARGET MyProject
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${file}" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Debug"
    )
endforeach()
```

Now I want to copy more files from a different folder. So we want to copy files from both `path/to/files` and `path/to/files2` to the same place in the binary folder. One way would be to just duplicate the above code, but it seems unnecessary to duplicate the lengthy custom command.

Is there an easy way to use `file` (and possibly the `list` command as well) to concatenate two `GLOB` lists?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The [`file (GLOB ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob) command allows for specifying multiple globbing expressions:

```
file (GLOB files "path/to/files/*" "path/to/files2*")
```

Alternatively, use the [`list (APPEND ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#append) sub-command to merge lists, e.g.:

```
file (GLOB files "path/to/files/*")
file (GLOB files2 "path/to/files2*")
list (APPEND files ${files2})
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this will actually perform two separate globs. Is there a way to make CMake only perform one glob like you can do with `extglob` in the shell? This does unfortunately not work: `file(GLOB_RECURSE files *.{ext1,ext2,ext3})`

Answer (score 39):

I'd construct a list for each of the patterns and then concatenate the lists:

```
file(GLOB files1 "path/to/files1/*")
file(GLOB files2 "path/to/files2/*")
set(files ${files1} ${files2})
```

Comment: This is useful for mixing GLOB with GLOB_RECURSE